# Overloading Addition with Python Vectors

Tags: python, class

As you can see i've created a function that allows me to create and alter a vector. Now i'm trying to add vectors together using `def __add__(self, y)`. However, i'm getting an `IndexError`. Is there anything obvious you can see wrong with my code because I'm getting stuck.

```
    def __add__(self, y):
        self.vector = []
        for j in range(len(self.vector)):
            self.vector.append(self.vector[j] + y.self.vector[j])
        return Vec(self.vector)
```

Comment: Why is the first line of `__add__` `self.vector = []`. What do you think this does? What do you think `len(self.vector)` will return? What do you think will happen when `self.vector` is passed as the argument of `__init__` in the line `return Vec(self.vector)`?

Comment: Won't `len(self.vector)` allow the `__add__` function to add the numbers of the vector?

Comment: `len` doesn't "allow" anything. It returns a number. What number do you think it will return?

Comment: Why are you modifying `self` at all? Addition is supposed to return a new vector, not scramble the contents of the original.

Comment: And what do you expect `Vec(self.vector)` to do if the constructor takes a length, not a list?

Comment: @user2357112 Now i just realized that.. Why is it like that?

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few issues in your code:

- When you do `self.vector = []`, you are basically clearing your vector. That's makes it impossible to add it to the other vector.
- When you do `return Vec(self.vector)`, you're passing a list to the `Vec` constructor - but you've defined it to take a vector length.
- You can only add vectors that are the same length as each other - you don't check that that is the case.

The following is a possible implementation of `__add__` with those problems addressed:

```
def __add__(self, y):
    size = len(self.vector)
    if size != len(y.vector):
        raise ValueError("Vectors must be the same size.")

    result = Vec(size)
    for j in range(size):
        result.vector[j] = self.vector[j] + y.vector[j]

    return result
```

Comment: That looks more like a possible implementation of `__iadd__` than of `__add__`.